# How does the Substrate Node Template deal with command line arguments?

Tags: cli, dev

I'm reading the code of Substrate Node Template, trying to get a deeper understanding of the implementation of it. However, I stuck when I tried to find out how the node deals with command line arguments, such as `--dev`.

From what I have learned from the codes, I believe that the `SubstrateCli::from_iter` function is responsible for parsing command line arguments, and the program crashes at the `let matches = app.try_get_matches_from(iter).unwrap_or_else(|e| e.exit());` statement if I enter a incorrect cli argument(`--devx`, for instance). But how does the program know that `--devx` is incorrect while `--dev` is the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a built-in feature of clap instead of Substrate.

https://github.com/clap-rs/clap

Comment: And specifically, Substrate uses clap's derive macros (formerly known as structopt)

Comment: Could you please tell me if --dev is a built-in feature of clap? Also, is there a way for the node to determine if the user has provided this flag in the CLI?

Comment: First question clap is a cli framework, `--dev` is a custom flag that they use this framework to build. Second question https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/41ad4a6c9d712ac4b6e16e79a8b3837af8234f46/node/src/command.rs#L43.